# How to display month name in x axis of JQPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Here's my data example:
Hi, I'm using JQPlot for the first time and got stuck with displaying month name in x axis.

```
var s1 = [[1, 782751.00], [2, 112592.00], [3, 1350924.00], [4, 648777.00], [5, 725266.00], [6, 358824.00]]

var s2 = [[1, 16], [2, 20], [3, 22], [4, 20], [5, 21], [6, 10]]

var ticks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Here, 1,2,3...etc indicates serial number of month (as in 1 for jan,2 for feb...)

Currently it's showing these numbers...but I need to display it as jan,feb,mar,apr and so on..

I've tried `DATEPART(MONTH,CreatedDate)  AS value`  and  `CONVERT(char(3), CreatedDate, 0)` in query but then the graph doesn't show up...a little help will be much appreciated.

---

seems like it was quite simple :| :)

Made changes to get

```
var ticks = ['January','February','March','April','May'......]
```

query:

```
 SET DATEFORMAT DMY; 
                        SELECT value FROM
                        ( 
                        SELECT  DISTINCT CONVERT(char(3), CreatedDate, 100) as value,DATEPART(MONTH,CreatedDate) AS Sl
                        FROM SER_TB_JobInfo
                        WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE() ) A ORDER BY Sl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do translation on javascript side using some kind of "int to month" translator :

```
//Ticks you actually have
var ticks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
//Translator array to do conversion from integer to month
var translator = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

for(var i = 0; i < ticks.length; ++i){
 ticks[i] = translator[i];   
}
```

Ticks is now containing `["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]`